# Installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows7, now win7 wants me to format drive D?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, format

I have an ssd boot drive and a Hard disk drive, C: and D: respectively. I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 7 and when I rebooted to go to windows, drive D says it must be formatted. Is there anyway to fix this? Or will I lose all my data on that drive?

Comment: Please mention Where is you Windows? On SSD or HDD, Where is you Ubuntu, Which is primary drive. Which is your bootloder (GRUB or Win Bootloader). If possible provide disk configuration. It means output of following command in terminal `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Additional to what Samir asks, what program is telling you that it needs to format D. For what I know the only way it could ask that is if you tried to access D: using the Windows explorer when actually D: would be Ubuntu (Not a FAT32 or NTFS partition).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention exactly how you installed both os. A quick fix if D is the drive where you installed ubuntu, would be to go to windows and remove drive later from computer management. Go to `Computer-Right click- Management- Disk management` and remove 'D' Letter from that drive. now windows will not detect it. Tell me if some thing else that you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you installed Ubuntu on D:, you might not lose almost your data. Please don't install Ubuntu once you have well prepared a partition to install Ubuntu on. And if your data is very important, now you may want to ask for a service to recover your drive. Because you have just installed Ubuntu for a time, so your data is recoverable.

If you did not install Ubuntu on D:, but on a partition which was a part of D: previously, just run "cmd" from Run, then "chkdsk D:" to check the disk.

Because W7 still detects D:, so don't worry too much, just ask for someone who's good at this problem to help you check D: and recover your drive's files, that's for your drive's safety! Don't try to recover your drive yourself, you may lose all your data if you are not good at this.